# Manage two CheckBoxes with one Boolean ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms, boolean

I want to set one boolean with two checkboxes : one is the opposite of the other.

In my view ASPX, I would like to bind my second checkbox to the OPPOSITE 'isLocal' (comes from the database table, no model between):

```
<td align="left">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckIsLocal" runat="server" DataValueField="isLocal" AutoPostBack="true"/>
</td>
<td align="left">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckIsPan" runat="server" DataValueField="isLocal" AutoPostBack="true" />
</td>
```

In my code behind I trigger the check event for both and I try (failed) to trigger the other to change its value.

```
this.CheckIsLocal.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.Oncheckedchanged);
this.CheckIsPan.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.OncheckedPanchanged);

private void Oncheckedchanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox CheckLocal = (CheckBox)sender;
    CheckLocal.Checked = CheckLocal.Checked ? true : false;
    this.CheckIsPan.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.OncheckedPanchanged);
}

private void OncheckedPanchanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox CheckPan = (CheckBox)sender;
    CheckPan.Checked = CheckPan.Checked ? true : false;
    this.CheckIsLocal.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.Oncheckedchanged);
}
```

I have two checkboxes for UI purpose, I thought of a ToggleButton but I don't know how to implement it without external tools.

How to set my two checkboxes with my one boolean?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sure you don't want to use radio buttons?

Comment: Is that radio button any different ? I'll check this !

Comment: probably radiobuttonlist or checkboxlist is what ur looking for

Comment: Creating new event handlers inside the "changed" event doesn't look right at all.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Thanks dor the codinf analysis. Either way I'll go on using radiobuttonlist  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for my purpose I didn't need any event using the RadioButtonList.

In my view ASPX :

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radCheckIsLocal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Local" Value="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pan" Value="False" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In my codeBehind I don't need any event I just retrive my data string and save it as a bool :

```
object.isLocal = radCheckIsLocal.SelectedValue == "True" ? true : false;
```